# Send requests from android to Elasticsearch run locally on my pc

Tags: android, elasticsearch

Is it possible to send requests from an android device (not from an emulator) to my Elasticsearch server run locally?
What tecnology I should use?

Comment: Elasticsearch exposes a RESTful API which means that you have to use HTTP. What do you want to do? Code an app? If so, there seems to be a [java client library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html) which you can use.

Comment: I would like to code an android kotlin app that send information to elasticsearch for elaboration but I am not sure if it is possible and how that my smartphone,where the app will run, know where to send those info because the server is actually local on my pc

Comment: You will have to expose your elasticsearch server to your local network, if you are okay only using your app on your local network, or to the internet if you really need to acces it from anywhere but bear in mind that exposing a port to the internet is a risky thing.